# Magmi plugin execution order

Tags: magmi

I am using the Magmi Datapump API and Axel Norvell's Item Disabler plugin and I can't seem to get that plugin's afterImport method to be called prior to the standard Reindexer plugin's afterImport method.

According to [the Magmi wiki](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Developing_plugins#How_Plugins_are_called), the order is dependent on the plugin filenames, thus I would expect magmi_itemdisabler_plugin to come before magmi_reindexing_plugin but it isn't happening that way for me.

Thinking it possible the pathnames might impact it, I tried moving the Item Disabler plugin into the "base" plugins directory instead of "extra" with no success.

Any thoughts on why this might be occurring and what I could do to tweak the order?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to force the order is to rename the plugin file for the item disabler.

I personally use a custom reindexer plugin I wrote, which is why I don't have this issue.  The standard reindexer plugin does (for some reason) execute before my item disabler plugin event though it's alphabetically weighted above it.  Magmi might only match the sort order on strings before the underscore `_` which would explain why.

Try renaming `magmi_itemdisabler_plugin.php` to `itemdisabler_plugin.php`.

Since `itemdisabler` alphabetically comes before `magmi`, this should work.

---

If the above doesn't work, try prepending an `01_` to the itemdisabler plugin file like this: `01_magmi_itemdisabler_plugin.php`

Then add an `02_` to the reindex plugin like this `02_magmi_reindexing_plugin.php`.

Comment: Thanks, Axel, for your suggestions. I issued the following commands, in the appropriate directories:  
  
    mv magmi_itemdisabler_plugin.php 01_magmi_itemdisabler_plugin.php  
    mv magmi_reindexing_plugin.php 02_magmi_reindexing_plugin.php  
  
Alas, they still are executed in the "wrong" order.  
  
Thanks, too, for the Item Disabler plugin! :)